# translateY, vertical align content

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/0dd4gzy4/

I'm using this techique to vertical align content - http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

It aligns the content but also push it out of it's container.

Is it possible to align the content this way within it's container.

```
    .row{
        background: gray;
        color: white;
        min-height: 5em;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
    p{
        color: red;
    }
    .btn{
        background: red;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    p, .btn{
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
      transform: translate(0, -50%);
    }
```

Comment: [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/0dd4gzy4/1/)

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Your solution will work only for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use that technique to vertical align divs instead use this

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/0dd4gzy4/4/

for vertical aligning div

```
.row div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:none;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

for fixing responsive design

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .row div {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER -** You need to add styles to the parent too.

**LONG ANSWER-**

Add a style to the `div`s who are immediate children to `.row`

```
.row > div
{
    border: 1px solid yellow; /* to see what is going on. delete this if you may */
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Once you add this, the `p` and `.btn` know what height to refer to

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9b14rnzh/)